# GraphQL Ariadne python Getting 'Cannot return null for non-nullable field' though value is not null

Tags: python, graphql, ariadne-graphql

I am getting and error about returning null for the success field but it is included in my return payload.
return payload looks like this

```
{'success': True, 'GeneratedKeywords': [{'id': 1, 'file_id': 1, 'keywords': 'keyword', 'generated_date': '11-01-2021'}, {'id': 2, 'file_id': 1, 'keywords': 'keyword', 'generated_date': '11-01-2021'}]}
```

schema

```
type DocumentKeywords {
    id: ID!
    file_id: Int!
    keywords: String!
    generated_date: String!
}
type GetAllKeyowrdsResult {
    success: Boolean
    errors: [String]
    GeneratedKeywords: [DocumentKeywords]
}
type Query {
    GetAllKeywords: [GetAllKeyowrdsResult]
}
```

resolver code

````
def resolve_AllKeywords(obj, info):
    try:
        #print(GeneratedKeywords.query.all(), file=sys.stderr)
        #GKs = [genKeys.to_dict() for genKeys in GeneratedKeywords.query.all()]
        GKs = []
        for genKeys in GeneratedKeywords.query.all():
            print(genKeys, file=sys.stderr)
            GKs.append(genKeys.to_dict())
        print(GKs, file=sys.stderr)
        payload = {
            "success": True,
            "GeneratedKeywords": GKs
        }
        print(payload, file=sys.stderr)
    except Exception as error:
        payload = {
            "success": False,
            "errors": [str(error)]
        }
    return payload
    ```
````

Comment: if you make `success` non-nullable, do you get the same error?
`success: Boolean!`